# change navigationbar button colors for ios7

Tags: ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I am trying to find out how to change the text and arrow color of the `UINavigationBar` buttons.

I know how to change the `titleTextAttributes` but cannot find out how to do it to the buttons.

For example this is how I change the titleTextAttributes inside my AppDelegate

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]};
```

I have looked through the UINavigationBar docs and cannot find any button attributes so not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to change the text color and the color of the arrow in the navigation bar you can use this code (iOS 7):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

this code will also change the color of the buttons

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Tint Color can also be set on the Storyboard, including a place to set the Global Tint color.  The Global Tint Color is the tint color used by anything whose tint color is set to "default".

Comment: @llario what does the color change to for the button. What if we want a different color than what ios7 chooses.

Comment: @nhgrif the back arrow that is created automatically can not give a color to storyboard

Comment: The automatically created back arrow uses whatever color the navigation bar's Tint Color is set to.  This Tint Color can be set from the storyboard.

Comment: @nhgrif you're telling me that if i set the white color on navigationBar, the arrow will take the color of navigationBar??

Comment: Not the color of the navigation bar.  For the third time, the TINT COLOR on the navigation bar.  You can set the tint color from the storyboard.  You can set the tint color for individual items, or there's a place to set the global tint color, which is what all items using the default tint color will use.  If you go to the storyboard and set the tint color of your nav bar to white, then yes, the arrow will show up white.  But this is the TINT COLOR.

Comment: @nhgrif oh ok sorry I misunderstood, but IMHO I think they go well both solutions

Comment: Oh, there's nothing wrong with your solution, and your solution is definitely needed when you want to change it programmatically.  I was just adding that it can also be done via storyboard.  And the nice thing about the storyboard is the ability to set the global tint color.  I'm not certain how easy it is to set a global tint color programmatically.

Comment: @nhgrif you're absolutely right, I really do not know you could set a global color tint. thanks for this ;)

Comment: @logixologist I just noticed your comment.  It confuses me.  Setting the tint color sets the exact color for every button on the UI element using that tint color.  The `[UIColor redColor]` he uses here for the tint color will display the back button in the same shade of red that it would display if you set anything else to `redColor`.

Comment: It worked perfectly. To give further insight I am setting RGB values to an NSArray inside my NSUserDefaults that I read and it uses the RGB values to color anything that I have set up to use those values... sort of like a global value.. saves me changing things in 100 places.

Comment: @nhgrif... ok I will try that. I must have misunderstood what you said.

Answer (score 3):

You can globally change it as easy as this[image]